# Blockly change colors

Tags: blockly

I need to change the background of the toolbox
I tried to change in (it doesn`t work)

```
<style>
#blockly {
       position: fixed;
    }
    #blocklyMask {
       background-color: #f0f8ff;
    }
  </style>
```

In addition I need to change the border colors of blocks. Tried to play with stroke parameters with no progress

```
Blockly.defineBlocksWithJsonArray([{
        "type": "ball_number",
        "lastDummyAlign0": "CENTRE",
        "message0": "ball_number%1",
        "strokeColour": "#00ff00",
        "strokeWidth": "5",
        "args0": [{
            "type": "field_number",
            "name": "NUMBER",
            "value": 0,
            "min": 1,
            "max": 100
        }],
        "previousStatement": "ball_attribute",
        "nextStatement": "ball_attribute",
        "colour": "#48d1cc",
        "tooltip": "Type the ball number. In range [1...100]",
        "helpUrl": ""
    },
```

I found this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blockly/CvcHpS5v9bA
but it is for ios

Answer (score 2):

use the following css

```
div#blocklyDiv .blocklyToolboxDiv {
    background: #c2c2ff;
}
```